# ¿Como mover los elementos en android studio que se quedan por debajo de otros?

Tags: android-studio

Quiero mover el ScrollView un poco más hacia arriba con todos los botones que tiene dentro pero cada vez que intento arrastrarlo pincho un botón y muevo únicamente ese botón en vez de el ScrollView con todo los botones. Se que se puede mover en código o con los atributos pero, ¿sabéis alguna forma para hacerlo en la vista diseño arrastrando?

[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer desde el XML utilizando la propiedad del scrollview:

```
padding-top: 0px;
```

eso hara que no haga espacio entre la parte superior y el complemento scrollview